# Warning message related lucene occurs when I use deeplearning4j

Tags: java, lucene, word2vec

I use `Word2vec` in deeplearning4j to make word embedding matrix. for this works, my program read absolute roots of text files by `Vector<String>` and initialize `Iterator` and `Word2vec` variable. However, I met warning message when the program call fit method in deeplearning4j.

Here is a warning message.

> 14:06:56.556 [main] WARN  o.d.t.i.LuceneInvertedIndex - Couldn't
>   create index  org.apache.lucene.store.LockObtainFailedException: Lock
>   obtain timed out:
>   SleepingLockWrapper(MMapDirectory@/Users/jimin/Documents/Workspace/MakeVector/word2vec-index
>   lockFactory=org.apache.lucene.store.NativeFSLockFactory@e24ddd0):
>   org.apache.lucene.store.LockObtainFailedException: Lock held by this
>   virtual machine:
>   /Users/jhmin/Documents/Workspace/MakeVector/word2vec-index/write.lock
>     at
>   org.apache.lucene.store.SleepingLockWrapper.obtainLock(SleepingLockWrapper.java:102)
>   ~[lucene-core-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1 1703449 - noble - 2015-09-17 01:38:09]
>     at org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter.(IndexWriter.java:775)
>   ~[lucene-core-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1 1703449 - noble - 2015-09-17 01:38:09]
>     at
>   org.deeplearning4j.text.invertedindex.LuceneInvertedIndex.tryCreateWriter(LuceneInvertedIndex.java:609)
>   [deeplearning4j-nlp-0.4-rc3.6.jar:na]     at
>   org.deeplearning4j.text.invertedindex.LuceneInvertedIndex.getWriterWithRetry(LuceneInvertedIndex.java:574)
>   [deeplearning4j-nlp-0.4-rc3.6.jar:na]     at
>   org.deeplearning4j.text.invertedindex.LuceneInvertedIndex.getWriter(LuceneInvertedIndex.java:623)
>   [deeplearning4j-nlp-0.4-rc3.6.jar:na]     at
>   org.deeplearning4j.text.invertedindex.LuceneInvertedIndex.initReader(LuceneInvertedIndex.java:279)
>   [deeplearning4j-nlp-0.4-rc3.6.jar:na]     at
>   org.deeplearning4j.text.invertedindex.LuceneInvertedIndex.(LuceneInvertedIndex.java:102)
>   [deeplearning4j-nlp-0.4-rc3.6.jar:na]     at
>   org.deeplearning4j.text.invertedindex.LuceneInvertedIndex.(LuceneInvertedIndex.java:106)
>   [deeplearning4j-nlp-0.4-rc3.6.jar:na]     at
>   org.deeplearning4j.text.invertedindex.LuceneInvertedIndex$Builder.build(LuceneInvertedIndex.java:893)
>   [deeplearning4j-nlp-0.4-rc3.6.jar:na]     at
>   org.deeplearning4j.models.word2vec.Word2Vec.buildVocab(Word2Vec.java:276)
>   [deeplearning4j-nlp-0.4-rc3.6.jar:na]     at
>   org.deeplearning4j.models.word2vec.Word2Vec.fit(Word2Vec.java:104)
>   [deeplearning4j-nlp-0.4-rc3.6.jar:na]     at
>   jhmin.mining.test.word2vec.MakeVector.run(MakeVector.java:120)
>   [classes/:na]     at jhmin.mining.test.word2vec.App.main(App.java:9)
>   [classes/:na] Caused by:
>   org.apache.lucene.store.LockObtainFailedException: Lock held by this
>   virtual machine:
>   /Users/jhmin/Documents/Workspace/MakeVector/word2vec-index/write.lock
>     at
>   org.apache.lucene.store.NativeFSLockFactory.obtainFSLock(NativeFSLockFactory.java:127)
>   ~[lucene-core-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1 1703449 - noble - 2015-09-17 01:38:09]
>     at
>   org.apache.lucene.store.FSLockFactory.obtainLock(FSLockFactory.java:41)
>   ~[lucene-core-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1 1703449 - noble - 2015-09-17 01:38:09]
>     at
>   org.apache.lucene.store.BaseDirectory.obtainLock(BaseDirectory.java:45)
>   ~[lucene-core-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1 1703449 - noble - 2015-09-17 01:38:09]
>     at
>   org.apache.lucene.store.SleepingLockWrapper.obtainLock(SleepingLockWrapper.java:84)
>   ~[lucene-core-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1 1703449 - noble - 2015-09-17 01:38:09]
>     ... 12 common frames omitted

How can't I fix this warning message?

Answer (score 0):

Update: we've moved away from lucene. You shouldn't see stuff like that anymore.